# Raise bounty on question

Tags: support, bounties

I have this question here: [iPad frame width and height mixup in landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641715/ipad-width-and-height-mixup-in-landscape)

I chose 500 then before accepting decided that was too much and halfed it, but now I just want the answer so I'd like to raise it to 500 but I can't find how to it. Also it's just such an irritating problem that I'd give all my rep away if I could to the clever person who has the answer.

It would be nice to have a few minutes after creating the bounty to be able to raise it. But for now could a mod or something please raise it for me to 500.

Comment: In the future, you can flag your question for mod attention to make requests like this; the community can't really help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a normal user, you can't change the amount of a bounty once it's set, either more or less, or cancel it altogether. The only recourse is for a mod to refund the bounty, but that is reserved for dire/special circumstances.

Since you set the bounty amount for half of what you wanted, you're in luck to solve this on your own: proceed as normal by awarding the first bounty as appropriate, then set and award a second bounty to make up the other half of what you wanted to set originally.

Comment: Be aware that 24 hours must pass starting and awarding a bounty.