# Is there any way to edit the bounty amount I allocated for a question?

Tags: support, bounties

I posted a question with a bounty reward of 50. Can I edit it to make it 100?

Comment: @HDE226868 oops! Reopened, will try to find the real dupe, still sure there is one..

Comment: @ShadowWizard http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27839/260841 or http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138963/260841?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ well, found [100% exact match](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67911/raise-bounty-on-question) but since this one here got a better answer, decided to close the old as dupe of the new. Hopefully that's the end of it. Also, this led me use the hammer to re-close an old question properly - something I love doing, so thanks! :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard fair enough :) Retracted CV

Answer (score 7):

**No.**

As per [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/274942),

> You can offer as many bounties on a question as you want. However, only one bounty can be active on a question at a time. Moreover, any user may have [at most 3 concurrent bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54315/why-cant-a-user-have-simultaneous-bounties-any-more/104813#104813) at a time.

Increasing the bounty amount counts as adding a second bounty.

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27916/274942) responds to the idea of raising a bounty after it is set (as opposed to the solution that was adopted, which is starting a new bounty afterwards).

My two cents are that it's fine to just put a second bounty up later. The same amount of rep can be transferred, and the question will get attention for a longer period. However, as the first answer I referenced states,

> Note that if you offer several bounties on the same question, [you will have to double the amount each time (or more)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit/105639#105639). That is, if your first bounty was worth 50 reputation, your second bounty on the same question will have to be for at least 100, your third for at least 200 and so on.

So if you offer a bounty for 200 rep points, and wanted to offer one instead for 250 rep points, you're in trouble.

Comment: I think (might be wrong!) That if you post another bounty on the same question then you must have a minimum value of double the original...?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ is correct, the same answer quoted here continues in "Note that if you offer several bounties on the same question, you will have to double the amount each time (or more)."

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Looks like [that's true](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit/105639#105639). I'll include that.

Comment: `Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on).` (http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)

Comment: lol -- everyone commented at nearly the exact same time :P

Comment: As usual, I'm to blame. ;)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ thanks, I knew there's exact match out there, it was just a matter of time until I hunt it down. :)